# Change sa.Column nullable property with Alembic in Batch mode

Tags: database, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a database upgrade migration I want to apply to Database column:

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    with op.batch_alter_table('details') as batch_op:
        batch_op.alter_column('details', 'non_essential_cookies',
                              existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
                              nullable=False)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

I am implementing batch mode sice ALTER is unsupported and previously I received this error : `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "ALTER":`. However, I hoped batch mode would work but now instead I receive the new error:

`TypeError: <flask_script.commands.Command object at 0x1149bb278>: alter_column() got multiple values for argument 'nullable'.`

I only have one tuple in the table and the relevant attribute is not NULL so the database migration is valid. I just don't understand why there are multiple values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [docs](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html):

> The method is used as a context manager, which returns an instance of
>   BatchOperations; this object is the same as Operations except that
>   table names and schema names are omitted.

Key point here being that you don’t have to provide the table name when calling ops on the `BatchOperations` instance.

The signature for `alter_column` is:

```
alter_column(table_name, column_name, nullable=None, server_default=False, new_column_name=None, type_=None, existing_type=None, existing_server_default=False, existing_nullable=None, schema=None, **kw)
```

So from your code:

```
with op.batch_alter_table('details') as batch_op:
        batch_op.alter_column('details', 'non_essential_cookies',
                              existing_type=sa.BOOLEAN(),
                              nullable=False)
```

`'details'` is being passed to `column_name`, and `'non_essential_cookies'` is getting passed to `nullable` as a positional argument. The issue is caused later when you specify the value of `nullable` again with the keyword arg,`nullable=False`.

Comment: yes, yes, clearly very simple (when its pointed out to me). Works like a charm, tvm. Seems you have a knack for finding my questions.. I still have one or two currently outstanding without answers!